# Plots with only a few scattered marks and correct legend

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I would like to draw several plots with lines and only a few marks.
The markes are irregularely spaced, so I used a method alluded to in
the pgfplots manual, section 4.8.5 (Legend appearance),  page 159,
`every legend image post` entry.
The lines and the marks are created by different `\addplot` commands.
The issue with this method is to have a legend showing both the lines
and marks.

Here is an adaptation of the code provided in the pgfplots manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend image post style={mark=*}]
\addplot+[only marks,forget plot]coordinates {(0.5,-0.5) (1,-1) (1.5,-1.5)};
\addplot+[mark=none,smooth,domain=0:2]{-x};
\addlegendentry{Parabola}

\addplot+[only marks,forget plot]coordinates {(0.3,0.3) (0.45,0.45) (1.7,1.7)};
\addplot+[mark=none,smooth,domain=0:2]{x};
\addlegendentry{Parabola}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code works when there is only one curve because one can specify
the plot mark in the `legend image post style` key.
However, do you know how this could be adapted to several plots with
different plotmarks ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By providing the `legend image post style` to each `\addplot` command instead of  to the `axis`, it only applies to each individual plot:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[only marks,forget plot]coordinates {(0.5,-0.5) (1,-1) (1.5,-1.5)};
\addplot+[mark=none,smooth,domain=0:2,legend image post style={mark=*}]{-x};
\addlegendentry{Parabola}

\addplot+[only marks,forget plot]coordinates {(0.3,0.3) (0.45,0.45) (1.7,1.7)};
\addplot+[mark=none,smooth,domain=0:2,legend image post style={mark=square*}]{x};
\addlegendentry{Parabola}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works indeed. Would there be a way to achieve the same result without having to manualy specify each mark ?
Something like `legend image post style=has mark` so that the legend use the cycle list.